# How to split a const char *?

Tags: c, string, constants, strtok

I have a `const char*` which represents a path I want to split it into an array of strings at character `/` so I can do the search step by step.

I tried doing

`char* str2 = strtok(str1,"/")`

but my compiler returns a

> warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type

How can I do the split without any warning?

Comment: for [strtok](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) only delimiter is `const`  your `str1` should not be `const`

Comment: Unfortunatly i do not have a choice in that matter

Comment: You will need to make a non-const copy of the string then.

Comment: Aside: not sure if relevent, but if you want to treat "foo/bar" and "foo//bar" differently, `strtok` would be unsuitable because it only returns non-empty tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtok(3)` and `strtok_r(3)` mutate the string in place, which prevents you from passing a const string. You will want to pass a copy anyway, as you don't want your initial string to be mutated and become unusable.

Here's how you can do it with `strdup(3)`:

```
char* strtmp = strdup(str1);
char* str2 = strtok(strtmp,"/");
// Use str2 here
free(strtmp);
```

Comment: Note that the call to `free(strtmp);` will also free the data that all the pointers returned from `strtok()` refer to.